# Solve the matrix equation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices `D` and `Y`.

I want to find the matrix `G` according to this:

```
G*D = Y
```

Note that all of these matrices are not square matrices.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html), if you want to solve an equation of the form

```
xA = b
```

you can solve it by doing

```
x = b/A
```

---

Note that your system is underdetermined, and you cannot simply find a single solution without additional constraints. An example:

```
A=[1;2;3];
b=[14;32];
x=b/A;
x*A==b % check if solution is correct
[1,2,3;4,5,6]*A==b % another, equally correct solution
```

It "works", but without restating the problem you're not going to get at anything better.

Note this is [quite extensively explained in the same documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#bt7ov7u).

Comment: This require a square matrix with full rank, which is explicitly stated to not be the case here. also the usual way to do it is using `x=A\b`. Sorry, but -1 since this solution is incorrect

Comment: @patrik Sorry, but please reread the question: the OP wants `G` (the matrix on the left), and these operations do not require square matrices at all. I do agree it's a problem that admits more than one solution, but the question as stated is solved by the above.